# Add first letter of titles to array, then compare arrays

Tags: custom-post-types, php, array

I have a custom post called `foundation_firms`, from which I'd like to create an array of letters, each letter representing that there exists a post starting with that letter.

I've been trying to use `in_array()` to avoid adding a letter to the array if it already is in the array, however that approach hasn't been working for me. Anyone have any idea why? Here's my code thus far:

```
$alphas = range('A', 'Z');
$post_alphas = [];
$post_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'foundation_firms',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'title',
);
$firm_query = new WP_Query($post_args);
if($firm_query->have_posts()){
    while($firm_query->have_posts()){
        $firm_query-> the_post();
        $title = get_the_title();
        echo $title.'<br/>';
        $title_alpha = $title[0];
        if(!in_array($post_alphas, $title_alpha)){
            $post_alphas[] = $title_alpha;
        }
    }
}
$final_alpha = array_intersect($post_alphas, $alphas);
echo '<pre>'.var_dump($final_alpha).'</pre>';
```

Basically this just gives me an array of the first letter of each post, duplicates and all. Isn't the `in_array()` function supposed to eliminate that?

Thanks in advance to any takers here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments for `in_array()` are the wrong way round. Looking at the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) you can see that the first argument is the value you want to check (the 'needle') and the second argument is the array you want to check for it in (the 'haystack').

So this means it's always evaluating as `false`, meaning that the code inside the condition is running every time.

Just swap the arguments around to fix the issue:

```
if( ! in_array( $title_alpha, $post_alphas ) ) {
    $post_alphas[] = $title_alpha;
}
```

There's a (I think) cleaner way to do this though, with a bit less code. You can get the posts first, then use `array_map()` to replace every value in the array with just the first letter of each title. Then finally `array_unique()` to remove duplicates:

```
$posts = get_posts( array(
    'post_type'      => 'foundation_firms',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby'        => 'title',
) );

$letters = array_map( $posts, function( $post ) {
    return $post->post_title[0];
} );

$letters_unique = array_unique( $letters );
```